# Facing issue with tomcat connector

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, jboss

i connected tomcat connector with apache in redhat linux.after restarting of jboss server wont take's jboss request.here is my stack trace

help me how to solve this issue.

```
[Mon Sep 15 01:42:38 2014] [5411:140090475009792] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2673): (worker1) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of error during request sending (attempt=1) 
[Mon Sep 15 01:42:38 2014] [5411:140090475009792] [info] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (758): connect to ::1:8009 failed (errno=111) 
[Mon Sep 15 01:42:38 2014] [5411:140090475009792] [info] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (1019): Failed opening socket to (::1:8009) (errno=111) 
[Mon Sep 15 01:42:38 2014] [5411:140090475009792] [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1663): (worker1) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=111) 
[Mon Sep 15 01:42:38 2014] [5411:140090475009792] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2673): (worker1) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of error during request sending (attempt=2) 
[Mon Sep 15 01:42:38 2014] [5411:140090475009792] [error] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2693): (worker1) connecting to tomcat failed. 
[Mon Sep 15 01:42:38 2014] [5411:140090475009792] [info] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2806): Service error=-3 for worker=worker1 
[Mon Sep 15 01:42:40 2014] [5622:140090483402496] [info] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (758): connect to ::1:8009 failed (errno=111) 
[Mon Sep 15 01:42:40 2014] [5622:140090483402496] [info] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (1019): Failed opening socket to (::1:8009) (errno=111) 
[Mon Sep 15 01:42:40 2014] [5622:140090483402496] [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1663): (worker1) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=111)
```

Comment: Looks to be issue connecting to worker1, does worker2 works?

Answer (score 0):

i have installed 1.2.40 version of tomcat connector later on moved to older version 1.2.35 then it works ....